# How to convert all column values to dates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm trying to convert all data in a column from the below to dates.

| Event Date |
| --- |
| 2020-07-16 00:00:00 |
| 31/03/2022, 26/11/2018, 31/01/2028 |

This is just a small section of the data - there are more columns/rows.

I've tried to split out the cells with multiple values using the below:

```
df["Event Date"] = df["Event Date"].str.replace(' ', '')
df["Event Date"] = df["Event Date"].str.split(",")
df= df.explode("Event Date")
```

The issue with this is it sets any cell without a ',' e.g. '2020-07-16 00:00:00' to NaN.

Is there any way to separate the values with a ',' and set the entire column to date types?

Comment: Are you saying that sometimes you don't know the format of the time in the column and/or there could be multiple times in a column?

Comment: In general, I would always use utils to handle datetime. I have never written robust code that handles all of the edge cases by hand. Use dateutil from parser.

Comment: Yes, the rows could be in either format as the table above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use combination of split and explode to separate dates and then use infer_datetime_format to convert mixed date types

```
df = df.assign(dates=df['dates'].str.split(',')).explode('dates')
df
Out[18]: 
                 dates
0  2020-07-16 00:00:00
1           31/03/2022
1           26/11/2018
1           31/01/2028 

df.dates = pd.to_datetime(df.dates,  infer_datetime_format=True)

df.dates
Out[20]: 
0   2020-07-16
1   2022-03-31
1   2018-11-26
1   2028-01-31
Name: dates, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition with [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`pandas.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) :

```
s_dates = (
            df["Event Date"]
                .str.split(",")
                .explode(ignore_index=True)
                .apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)
           )
```

Output :

```
0   2020-07-16
1   2022-03-31
2   2018-11-26
3   2028-01-31
Name: Event Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: This errors as such: ValueError: day is out of range for month present at position 0

Comment: The code works fine with the example you shared. You can add `errors="coerce"` to the apply function and see what rows are `NaT`.

Comment: I'm thinking something along the lines of: # for row in auto_test_file['Event Date']:

     if ',' in df["Event Date"].values():
         df["Event Date"] = df["Event Date"].str.replace(' ', '')
         df["Event Date"] = df["Event Date"].str.split(",")
         df= df.explode("Event Date")

Comment: I suggest you to avoid for loops. Your goal is easy to achieve without any loop.

Comment: This sets any row without a ',' to NaT.

Answer (score 0):

Your example table shows mixed date formats in each row. The idea is to try a date parsing technique and then try another if it fails. Using loops and having such wide variations of data types are red flags with a script design. I recommend using datetime and dateutil to handle the dates.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser

date_strings = ["2020-07-16 00:00:00", "31/03/2022, 26/11/2018, 31/01/2028"] % Get these from your table.
parsed_dates = []

for date_string in date_strings:
    try:
        # strptime
        date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        parsed_dates.append(date_object)
    except ValueError:
        # parser.parse() and split
        date_strings = date_string.split(",")
        for date_str in date_strings:
            date_str = date_str.strip()
            date_object = parser.parse(date_str, dayfirst=True)
            parsed_dates.append(date_object)

print(parsed_dates)
```

Try the code on Trinket: https://trinket.io/python3/95c0d14271

Comment: I've tried this as below: parsed_dates = []

for row in auto_test_file['Event Date']:
    try:
        # strptime
        date_object = datetime.strptime(row, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        parsed_dates.append(date_object)
    except ValueError:
        # parser.parse() and split
        date_strings = row.split(",")
        for date_str in row:
            date_str = date_str.strip()
            date_object = parser.parse(date_str, dayfirst=True)
            parsed_dates.append(date_object)

This errors with TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float

Comment: Maybe something is with the table of dates that you have. try breaking down the problem. 1) get the data from the table, 2) try to parse the data for times - You might be reading the header of the table or something. Try the Trinket that I shared. This works perfectly for me.